# Выделение районов области в google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Как можно выделить район области в google maps?. Выделение областей описано в API, а выделение районов не нашел. Пример на карте.[image: Пример]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Сергей, вы нашли ответ на данный вопрос? Прошу, поделитесь им!